# What is &H14& in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, numbers, hex

I found the following article : [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/apr08/hey0425.mspx) about installing fonts on a Windows computer via a script. The author uses VBScript to do that, but I'd like to use Ruby/Python. There is a line in the script I don't understand :

```
Const FONTS = &H14&
```

What is that &H14&? Is it a number? How would I represent that in another language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a number in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). &H14& can be written in some programming languages as 0x14.

The value is used to represent the special folder "Fonts" .. [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774096%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

The &H prefix is used to write a number in hexadecimal. The hexadecimal number 14 is the decimal number 20.

The & suffix means that the number is of the type Long (32 bit integer).

So, &H14& is a numeric literal of the type Long with the value 20.